# Can't combine *ngFor and *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have a need to bind an *ngFor loop to a div, but I also need to only display it after meeting an *ngIf condition.

But Angular 4 won't let you combine them.

My code:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right positive" 
*ngFor="let phone of contact.shared.phones"
*ngIf="phone.phone_number !== ''">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
  <small>{{phone.phone_type}} phone</small>
  <br>{{phone.phone_number | tel}}
  <i class="icon ion-android-close" (click)="removePhone($index, phone)"></i>
</ion-item>
```

I get the following error:

Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *

So how do you go about doing that?

Comment: You cant add both for and if condition in angular instead you can give it in another div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the *ngFor directive element in an ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="">
  <ion-item *ngFor=""></ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks, Carsten!

Comment: Works great for ion-slides too.
Example: 
<ion-slides #slides>
<ng-container *ngFor="let now of days; let i = index;">
<ion-slide *ngIf="now != 0 && now != 6 && now != 7">
...